# SQL Select counter when values change

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to make a counter for everytime a value changes in time.
I have this table:

```
  Date      |   Quantity
2017-02-01  |    10000
2017-02-02  |    20000
2017-02-03  |    20000
2017-02-04  |    20000
2017-02-05  |    10000
2017-02-06  |    10000
```

I want to make something like this:

```
  Date      |   Quantity   | Counter
2017-02-01  |    10000     |    1
2017-02-02  |    20000     |    2
2017-02-03  |    20000     |    2
2017-02-04  |    20000     |    2
2017-02-05  |    10000     |    3
2017-02-06  |    10000     |    3
```

I tried using dense_rank and other functions but I couldn't make it look like that because it would give the same Counter number when the quantity is 10000.

Is what I'm asking even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What version of Oracle? In Oracle 12 or above there's a very simple and very efficient solution with MATCH_RECOGNIZE.

Comment: I'll look into that. thanks

Comment: "Look into" what version you have? You can run `select * from v$version`, you will get your answer right away.

Answer (score 4):

A simple method is to use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.date, t.quantity,
       sum(case when quantity = prev_quantity then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date) as counter
from (select t.*, lag(quantity) over (order by date) as prev_quantity
      from t
     ) t;
```

These are ANSI standard functions and available in most databases.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution for Oracle 12 and above **only**, using the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause:

```
with
     test_data ( dt, quantity ) as (
       select date '2017-02-01', 10000 from dual union all
       select date '2017-02-02', 20000 from dual union all
       select date '2017-02-03', 20000 from dual union all
       select date '2017-02-04', 20000 from dual union all
       select date '2017-02-05', 10000 from dual union all
       select date '2017-02-06', 10000 from dual
     )
-- end of test data, for illustration only; WITH clause is NOT part of the query
-- solution (SQL query) begins BELOW THIS LINE
select dt, quantity, mn as counter
from   test_data
match_recognize (
  order by dt
  measures match_number() as mn
  all rows per match
  pattern ( a b* )
  define b as b.quantity = a.quantity
)
;

DT           QUANTITY    COUNTER
---------- ---------- ----------
2017-02-01      10000          1
2017-02-02      20000          2
2017-02-03      20000          2
2017-02-04      20000          2
2017-02-05      10000          3
2017-02-06      10000          3

6 rows selected.
```